# SQL Exception - column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. my data is not null though

Tags: sql-server, debugging, null, sqlexception

What could be causing this exception when my object that i am inserting does not have any null values?
I have debugged and looked at the object, no null values, yet it still throws an exception. The only thing i can think of is that the definition for the column had previously read

```
identity(1,1) not null
```

and i changed it to just

```
not null
```

any ideas?

my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
    [ProductId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [Enabled]          BIT             CONSTRAINT [DF_Stock_Enabled] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Sort]             INT             NOT NULL,
    [ProductPrice] DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Stock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stock_Products] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products]      ([ProductId])
);
```

Comment: What is the schema of the table and what is the `INSERT` statement being executed?  If you changed an `identity` column to no longer be an `identity`, are you providing a value for that column?

Comment: Use profiler, find failing query. Or turn on SQL logging in your app.

Comment: yes i am undoubtedly providing a value for the column.   i think the error has something to do with the fact that the table was originally created with the identity(1,1) and then that was removed.

Comment: @user1977591: Terms like "undoubtedly" and "I think..." pale in comparison to actual debugging information.  If an `INSERT` query is failing, looking at the query itself as well as the table schema would be a good start...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IDENTITY means it will generate an incremented value for that column on inserts. Removing that means that any inserts to that table will now fail as it no longer automatically generates that sequence number.

Comment: Unless the `INSERT` includes a value for that column.  We can't know since the OP hasn't shared any actual information on the code which is failing.  Though I agree that this is *likely* the problem.

Comment: Only if `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] ON`.
Which is to say unless it was already on, he could NOT have been inserting into the column already. If it was set to OFF his inserts would have failed.

Comment: If the column is no longer an identity then that shouldn't be necessary to insert a value.  (The error would be different if it was an identity and a value was provided without turning that on.)  But if the column is not an identity and doesn't allow nulls then the observed error *would* happen if no value is provided.

Answer (score 0):

When you have identity(1,1) not null it means that you don't have to provide values to that column. SQL Server increments the value for itself(if IDENTITY_INSERT is turned off on that table).

When you changed it to just not null, you have to provide value for that column. Check in SQL SERVER Profiler the statement generated.